# What do serif and sans-serif mean?

Tags: css

What is the difference between serif and sans-serif in the CSS `font-family` property?

Comment: See `<generic-name>` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Comment: https://medium.com/@nerimbarakat/the-fundamental-elements-of-design-4266fa0df7aa

Answer (score 7):

They are styles of font. Serif includes small lines, Sans Serif (sans means without) doesn't include them.

They are "system fonts", the browser will have a default font to use for each type in the system. You don't have control over them but they are good fallbacks if the font you want isn't on the users system. You can specify a comma list of fonts to try and use in CSS

```
font-family: "Times new roman", serif;
```

or

```
font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif

Answer (score 0):

Serif fonts have a slight slight projection finishing off a stroke of a letter in certain typefaces whereas sans-serif fonts do not.

The CSS property of `font-family` can have either serif or sans-serif set as the property value. Based on which you have chosen, it will load the native font of the browser the visitor is currently using.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp